# set html5 canvas dimensions using variables

Tags: html, canvas

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="250" height="150">
</canvas>
```

Instead of using specific numbers (250 by 150), I want to set variables outside my canvas and use those variable values, along these lines:

```
myCanvasWidth = 250
myCanvasHeight = 150
<canvas id="myCanvas width = myCanvasWidth height = myCanvasHeight>
</canvas>
```

How can I achieve this?
Thanks.

Comment: In JS, get a reference to the canvas and set its width/height properties: <script>
 window.onload=function(){
    var canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var w=250;
    var h=150;
    canvas.width=w;
    canvas.height=h;
 }
 </script>

Answer (score 0):

You could not create your Canvas directly in the webpage but create a container for it and do everything else in JavaScript :

HTML

```
<div id = "container"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
function Engine(name, width, height)
{
    var that = this, running = false, interval = 0;

    that.name = "";
    that.canvas = null;
    that.scene = new Array();

    that.Init = function(name, width, height)
    {
        that.name = name;
        that.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        that.canvas.width = width;
        that.canvas.height = height;
    };

    that.Append = function(id)
    {  
        var el = document.getElementById(id);
        if(el && el.appendChild)
        {
            el.appendChild(that.canvas);
        }
    };

    var Render = function(_callback_)
    { 
        // Clear the screen | For each object of scene render and callback
    };

    var Update = function(_callback_)
    {
        // Compute physics if needed | For each object callback
    };

    that.Run = function(render, _update)
    {
        if(!running)
        {
            running = true;
            interval = setInterval(function(){
                Render(_render);
                Update(_update);
            }, 16);
        }
    };

    that.Clear = function()
    {
        if(!running)
        {
            running = false;
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    };

    that.Init(name, width, height);
}

/* Exemple */
var app = new Engine("test", 640, 480);

app.Append("container");

app.Run(function render(){
    // render
}, function update(){
    // logic
});
```